# Injection in Keystone (Openstack)

Tags: sql, code-injection, openstack, keystone

i'm studying where Keystone has an injection attack or not.
after trying to input some code when login, i need to see the source code to know where any filter the input text.

but i can not find which file of keystone source code to open to show that
here is source code: https://github.com/openstack/keystone
plz help me

Answer (score 2):

> i'm studying where Keystone has an injection attack or not. after trying to input some code when login, i need to see the source code to know where any filter the input text.

Keystone is a identify service, doesn't have any input. Maybe you mean login to horizon.

Horizon is a Django-based project. Its login view is in [django-openstack-auth](https://github.com/openstack/django_openstack_auth). The login function is in file django_openstack_auth/openstack_auth/views.py.

Comment: yes , im studying the openstack and want to test if there is any injection attack. thanks so much for your help. as i know if a system want to avoid injection , it need to filter the input of user when login, so with Django, is there any protection  to avoid that. i read the views.py but can not recognize that :(

Comment: [This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/security/#sql-injection-protection) may help you.